# Lightweight, compliant, cross-platform WebView?

Tags: python, html, chromium, gecko

I'm a Python/Web dev who wants to build rich desktop applications. After realizing that both [Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) and [Kivy](http://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/rules.html) are trying to ram a shitty DSL down my throat (not saying that's a necessarily bad thing, I just kind of have an aversion to it), I thought I'd much rather work with the technologies I feel most comfortable with - namely, HTML5/CSS/JS on the front end and a back end driven by something like Tornado or Node.js.

What options would I then have for the container which would run the front end? Everything just looks so bloated and unwieldy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some success with running [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) via its [Python bindings](https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/). I'd like to play around with a Gecko-based analogue, though.